# How to connect output of a module to its input?

Tags: system-verilog

How to tell in SystemVerilog that one of the module's outputs is directly connected to one of it's inputs?

Does it depend on the modeling level used? If yes, what is the right way for switch level?

```
module abc (input in1, in2, output out1, out2, out3);

// out3 needs to be directly connected to in1
// ...

endmodule
```

Comment: I assume your looking for a more system-verilog idiomatic way than the traditional Verilog method of `assign out3 = in1;` ?

Comment: Yes, SystemVerilog way is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. But not all downstream tools like synthesis physical tools may support it.

This is the way to do it in SystemVerilog

```
module abc (input in1, in2, output out1, out2, out3);
// out3 needs to be directly connected to in1
// ...
alias out3 = in1;
endmodule
```

In Verilog

```
module abc (input .in1(sig), in2, output out1, out2, .out3(sig));
wire sig;
// out3 needs to be directly connected to in1
// ...
endmodule
```

Comment: OK, but can you say that either `alias`, or `assign`, or connecting both ports to an internal net is better for some reason than the others for SystemVerilog (apart from current support by tools)?

Comment: If you want a direct connection for a switch-level netlist, then use `alias`. You lose strength propagation through an `assign` statement. If you are writing RTL, then an `assign` would be fine.